# Centroid of circle having two fixed points and one variable point

Tags: geometry, circles

B and C are the fixed points having coordinates $(3,0)$ and $(-3,0)$ respectively. If vertical angle BAC is 90 degree then the locus of centroid of triangle ABC has the equation....

$A.x^2+y2=1$

$B.x^2+y^2=2$

$C.9(x^2+y^2)=1$

$D.9(x^2+y^2)=4$

Comment: The point $A' = (0,3)$ lies on the locus of $A$. Among the four given circles,  which one contains the centroid of triangle $A'BC$?

Comment: According to the given, C is a point on the circle with AB as diameter. Its center is ... at (0, 0). Let the centroid be at (h, k). Then C = ... = (3h, 3k). Note that C(3h, 3k) satisfies the equation $(3h)^2 + (3k)^2 = 3^2$. Therefore, we have $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If angle $BAC$ is $90°$ then $A$ is on the circle $x^2+y^2=9$

Centroid $G$ has coordinates $\left(\dfrac{-3+x_A+3}{3},\;\dfrac{0+y_A+0}{3}\right)\equiv \left(\dfrac{x_A}{3},\;\dfrac{y_A}{3}\right)$

As vertex $A$ lies on the circle its coordinates satisfy $x_A^2+y_A^2=9$ which dividing both sides by $9$ becomes $\left(\dfrac{x_A}{3}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{y_A}{3}\right)^2=1$

therefore centroid $G(x,y)$ will satisfy $x^2+y^2=1$

[image]